# Firebase many to many performance

Tags: performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm wondering about the performance of Firebase when making n + 1 queries. Let's consider the example in this article https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html where a link has many comments. If I want to get all of the comments for a link I have to:

1. Make 1 query to get the index of comments under the link
2. For each comment ID, make a query to get that comment.

Here's the sample code from that article that fetches all comments belonging to a link:

```
var commentsRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/comments");
var linkRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/links");
var linkCommentsRef = linkRef.child(LINK_ID).child("comments");
linkCommentsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  commentsRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function() {
    // Render the comment on the link page.
  ));
});
```

I'm wondering if this is a performance concern as compared to the equivalent of this query if I were using a SQL database where I could make a single query on comments: `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE link_id = LINK_ID` clause.

Imagine I have a link with 1000 comments. In SQL this would be a single query, but in Firebase this would be 1001 queries. Should I be worried about the performance of this?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that Firebase works over web sockets (where available), so while there may be 1001 round trips there is only one connection that needs to be established. Also: a lot of the round trips will be happening in parallel. So you might be surprised at how much time this takes.

> Should I worry about this?

In general people over-estimate the amount of use they'll get. So (again: in general) I recommend that you don't worry about it until you actually have that many comments. But from day 1, ensure that nothing you do today precludes optimizing later.

One way to optimize is to further denormalize your data. If you already know that you need all comments every time you render an article, you can also consider duplicating the comments into the article.

A fairly common scenario:

```
/users
  twitter:4784
    name: "Frank van Puffelen"
    otherData: ....
/messages
  -J4377684
     text: "Hello world"
     uid: "twitter:4784"
     name: "Frank van Puffelen"
  -J4377964
     text: "Welcome to StackOverflow"
     uid: "twitter:4784"
     name: "Frank van Puffelen"
```

So in the above data snippet I store both the user's uid *and* their name for every message. While I could look up the name from the uid, having the name in the messages means I can display the messages without the lookup. I'm also keeping the uid, so that I provide a link to the user's profile page (or other message).

We recently had a good question about this, where I wrote more about the approaches I consider for keeping the derived data up to date: [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)