# best practice for data synchronization in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, firebase, synchronization

I'm trying to do some integration between two systems, and I've got some problems when it comes to synchronizing data.

I am using ***nodejs*** and the database is ***mongodb*** or ***firebase***.

The scenario is described as below:

- systemA with dbA
- systemB with dbB

Do the following:

1. systemA sends a request (POST or PUT whatever) to systemB, the `body` is like this:

   ```
   {
     .....
     fieldA1: valueA1,
     fieldA2: valueA2
     .....
   }
   ```
2. then systemB needs to update several fields(fieldB1, fieldB2) in dbB according to the systemA data, like this:

   ```
   fieldB1: valueA1
   ```

   ```
   fieldB2: valueA2
   ```
3. after **BOTH** `fieldB1` and `fieldB2` are updated successfully, then execute more logic

I'm using `async` to control asynchronous process. My code to implement these 3 steps:

```
async.waterfall([
  function (callback) {
    //get valueA1 of fieldA1 and valueA2 of fieldA2
  },

  async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
      //set valueA1 to fieldB1
    },

    function (callback) {
      //set valueA2 to fieldB2
    }
  ], function (err, result) {
      //more logic here
  })
], function (err, result) {
  //more logic here
})
```

Since `fieldB1` and `fieldB2` should be updated *at the same time*, either situation when failing to update `fieldB1` or `fieldB2` will lead to data inconsistency, which is not the correct result.

However, `async.parallel` cannot guarantee that any update failure will rollback or prevent the others' update right ? Is there any way to idealy keep the data consistency of **BOTH** when updating `fieldB1` and `fieldB2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it difficult to map your code to the Firebase API. But what you're describing sounds like its achievable by either using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) or [multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html).

I covered these type of updates in-depth in the past in: [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)

Comment: Thanks so much Frank! your multi-location updates part seems like to be similar to what I've met with and I really get help from that.