# How to update old data with new data in Firebase?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a chat app. In my app there are 4 nodes called `User, Recent, Message, Group`. I'm using Objective-C My message object looks like,

```
{
    "createdAt" : 1.486618017521277E9,
    "groupId" : "-KcWKeXXQ9tjYsYfCknx",
    "objectId" : "-KcWKftK8GiMxxAnarL5",
    "senderId" : "828949592937598976",
    "senderImage" : "http://hairstyleonpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/marcello-alvarez.png",
    "senderName" : "John Doee",
    "status" : "Seen",
    "text" : "Hi all",
    "type" : "text",
    "updatedAt" : 1.486622011467733E9
}
```

When I'm updating a User, all message's `senderName` should be updated accordingly. Is there are way to do this via the code or Do I need to write a rule. I'm a newbie to the firebase. Please suggest me a way to do that. If It's possible to do with the rules, Please guide me on this.

Comment: You'll have to update it manually. There is no code that will do it for you.

Comment: See my answer here for the possible approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277#30699277. The answer is for JavaScript, but the approaches are valid on any platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this via rules, so you have to manually iterate over all your data and update the senderName.

Anyways, I think you would probably be better off with saving {senderID: $someUserID} instead - like you would do in a relational database. The userID is static, so can change the user without having to update all the instances where you use it.