# How can I track and update all branches of common data set in firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Consider the following firebase tree where I have a primary node called `users` that holds name, avatar, email and other user stuff that I use and are replied across other nodes.

I have another primary node called `games`. One user can play many games alone or with other players.

If a user **er09gju34900jf23** decides to update its profile, how can I look to all my database where I have this *id* and update all paths at once?

```
{
    users: {
        er09gju34900jf23: { // Authenticated User ID
            avatar: '',
            email: '',
            name: '',
            // other user profile data
        }
    },
    games: {
        er09gju34900jf23: { // Authenticated User ID
            a2w4053g9043if092: { // Game Random Generate Game ID (1)
                // other data
                players: {
                    er09gju34900jf23: {
                        avatar: '',
                        email: '',
                        name: '',
                        // other user profile data
                    },
                    // other players
                }
            },
            bewrpgkrthg96k059h: { // Game Random Generate Game ID (2)
                // other data
                players: {
                    er09gju34900jf23: {
                        avatar: '',
                        email: '',
                        name: '',
                        // other user profile data
                    },
                    // other players
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this tree, how can I find out that **er09gju34900jf23** is a player in **a2w4053g9043if092** and **bewrpgkrthg96k059h** games and then update its data, like below:

```
/users/er09gju34900jf23 = {avatar, email, name}
/games/er09gju34900jf23/a2w4053g9043if092/players/er09gju34900jf23  = {avatar, email, name}
/games/er09gju34900jf23/bewrpgkrthg96k059h/players/er09gju34900jf23  = {avatar, email, name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend *not* replicating each user's full data under each game. Instead just replicate their UID under each game and then look up the information for each user from their `/users/$uid` node.

I'd also recommend:

- my answer on how to do fan-out of data (which is a fancy term for what you're asking): [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277#30699277)
- this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- our video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

Comment: Thanks Frank! Due to two of these links that I decided to adopt the structure described in my question. I am going to do a second read of theses recomendations. I comment again after reading.