# Firebase: handle setValue failure

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android app, I am using Firebase to store some user information.
I am storing user's `username` in 3 different places. 
I have this option in my app where I allow users to update their `username`. I want to know the best reliable way of updating the `username` in all those 3 places.

My approach is to do this:

-- Update in place 1. If that was successful, then update in place 2. If that was successful, then update in place 3. If that was successful, then I am all good. `username` got updated successfully in all 3 places.

But how would I handle a scenario like this:

-- Attempt to update in place 1. Let's say that was successful, then I attempt to update in place 2. Let's say that was successful too, then I attempt to update in place 3. Let's say that it failed to update in place 3. At this point, I have updated `username` in place 1 and place 2, but not in place 3.

That scenario can happen if user's phone disconnects from Wifi while Firebase is trying to update. And I want to handle it in a proper way if that happens. Below is some reference code on how I am doing this:

```
placeOneReference.child(key).setValue(newUsername)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            placeTwoReference.child(key).setValue(newUsername)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                placeThreeReference.child(key).setValue(newUsername)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    // Everything is successful
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Comment: This sounds very similar to [How to write denormalized data in Firebase
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase). Levi's answer is the top recommendation in my answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multipath update in this [case](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). This way you don't cascade the requests, but rather let firebase handle them in one "atomic" update function.

```
    Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
    value.put("username", username);

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/path1/" + key, value);
    childUpdates.put("/path2/" + key, value);
    childUpdates.put("/path3/" + key, value);



    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

You can even add a onComplete listener to update children if you want to be notified when it is done or if anything else (an error) happens.

```
mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is perfect! I forgot I could just use a HashMap