# How to update multiple nodes of Firebase Datbase basing on the query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update multiple nodes(based on query) on Firebase. Here's the structure of the database.
[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3MpW.png)
Suppose, I'm updating the user information for the user "user003". As soon as I update the name and image of the user "user003", I want to search the database whose whose are friends with user003, friends are denoted as friend_list on the database. SO, upon updating the user003 information, I want to update the user003's information on the friend_list too. Hope you understand what I wanted to do. Here's the illustration of the update:
[Upon update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INkVw.png).
I'm using the following code to update the user003 information to the Firebase Database:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child(Commonx.USER_INFORMATION);

HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();

userMap.put("name", fullNameEditText.getText().toString());
userMap.put("image", imageEditText.getText().toString());
userMap.put("image", myUrl);
ref.child(Commonx.loggedUser.getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);
```

Here `Commonx.USER_INFORMATION= "User information" on the database`. And, by `Commonx.loggedUser.getUid()= the userid of the database`.

Comment: i suggest to use Firebase function for something like this cause from above database structure. It is hard to find who is friends with user3

Comment: @Ashish I can keep the logged user data and just match with all the user's friend list, if the data matches then I can just update. The logic is simple but I don't know how to do in Firebase

Comment: do you have user friendlist of current logged in user ?

Comment: Sounds like a clear use-case, you'll need to perform an update for each user (or a single multi-location update across all of them). What problem do you have? If you're just looking for info on approaches, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase