# Firebase db rule to prevent delete related to another node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Assume that we have two nodes: "items" and "sales". How can I write a firebase db rule to prevent any item being deleted if it is related in another node. If a user wants to delete ("items\i01") it should not give permission because it is a relation under ("sales\s01\i01")

```
"items": {
   "i01": {
     "name": "item1"
   },
   "i02": {
     "name": "item2"
   },
}

"sales": {
   "s01": {
     "itemKey": "i01",
     "price": "45"
   },
   "s02": {
     "itemKey": "i02",
     "price": "60"
   },
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules can check whether data exists at a known path, but cannot perform searches for data across (a branch of) the JSON tree. So in your current data structure, there is no way to prevent the deletion of the item based on it still being referenced.

---

The typical solution would be to add a data structure that you can check in security rules to see if the item is still referenced anywhere. This would pretty much be an inverse of your current `sales` node, which tracks the items in a sale. The inverse node would track the sales for any item:

```
"sales_per_item": {
  "i01": {
    "s01": true
  },
  "i02": {
    "s02": true
  }
}
```

You will need to make sure that this new structure (sometimes called an inverted index) is updated to say in sync with `sales`, both in code and in security rules.

With that in place, you can then prevent deletion of an item that still has references with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      "$itemid": {
        ".write": "!newData.exists() && !newData.parent().parent().child('sales_per_item').child($itemid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

As an alternative, you can consider moving the deletion logic into a Cloud Function, where you can do the "check for orders with the item" in code, instead of in security rules.

I also recommend reading these:

- [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)
- [Patterns for security with Firebase: combine rules with Cloud Functions for more flexibility](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-combine-rules-with-cloud-functions-for-more-flexibility-d03cdc975f50)
- [Patterns for security with Firebase: offload client work to Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07)

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply. For my case, I decided to create a cloud function for delete operations. Links are very helpful.