# How to structure collections in Firestore and access them in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an social app using flutter, in that app I have users and their posts, so in firestore I am creating 2 collections,

1. Users
2. Posts

So, in users it will have user data like email, display picture, bio etc. For identification I'm creating a key in posts which will have a reference to the user to whom the post belongs, like so,

[image: Collections]

Now, I while I ask a particular post I also want some of the user details like UserName and display picture so that I can show it in the Post in the UI like,

[image: post]

So, I want to use StreamBuilder as it will reflect any changes made, but I can't get user details if I'm using StreamBuilder.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your data model, you need to make two queries, the first one to get the user ID and others to get the posts corresponding to the user.

```
final StreamController<List<Post>> _postsController =
      StreamController<List<Post>>.broadcast();

  Stream listenToPostsRealTime() {
    // Register the handler for when the posts data changes
    _postsCollectionReference.snapshots().listen((postsSnapshot) {
      if (postsSnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        var posts = postsSnapshot.documents
            .map((snapshot) => Post.fromMap(snapshot.data, snapshot.documentID))
            .where((mappedItem) => mappedItem.userId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().uid)
            .toList();

        // Add the posts onto the controller
        _postsController.add(posts);
      }
    });

    return _postsController.stream;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you to visit this video: "[How to structure your data](https://youtu.be/haMOUb3KVSo?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ)" and this [post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data), remember that you will be charged for every read to the database, so if you're going to gather information from the `Users` document every time you retrieve a Post, it would be a better idea to have duplicated information from the `Users` document inside your `Posts` document, this way you only have to query your `Posts` document. Remember that denormalizing data (like replicating it) on the NoSQL world is a common behaviour.
Your structure could be something similar to:

```
Posts:
createdAt: "June 25, 2020"
description: "New food"
email: "test@email.com"
image: "https://example.com/assets/image.jpg"

likes:
[updatedAt: "June 25,2020", user: likerUser]

user: 
[ name: posterUser, 
  profile_picture: "https://example.com/assets/posterPicture.jpg",
  profile_url: "https://example.com/profiles/userPoster"]
```

In order to keep your data synced between both documents I recommend you to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30699277/5495197)