# Develop blog post app having profile image and name with every post using firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to make a blog post web application using firebase. Each post will display name and profile image of at the top bar/header of post.

But due to media-token associated with each profile image file uploaded on Storage is unique. if a user update their profile pic then on blog post profile image doesn't load and show 'ERROR: 403' in console.

How we can manage to show user profile image and their name along with every post?
For example you can consider wall post of facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the profile image URL with each blog post, you will have to update each blog post when a user's profile image URL changes. For a few strategies on how to do that, see: [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase). While these are for the Firebase Realtime Database, the same approaches apply to Cloud Firestore.

Alternatively, you can only store a user's profile image URL in their own user document, and then look it up when displaying a blog post from that user. In that case you would only have to update the URL in the user's own document.

Comment: Hey Frank, I am already storing user's profile data(Name, ID, Profile IMG) in firebase realtime database and blogs I am storing in Firestore Database. If I do lookup for every post done by multiple users then query may takes time to fetch for profile image urls

Comment: Is there any way to ignore media token associated with each image, if can ignore then my problem would be solved. :)

Comment: You can set public access on the bucket, which would remove the need for a token and allows anyone to access files in that bucket. That's a Cloud Storage setting, outside of the scope of Firebase, so I'd recommend checking the Google Cloud Storage docs for how to do it.