# Can I create a symbolic link in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, symlink

In Linux one can [create a symbolic link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/). Using the `ln` command you could make one path location  "see" the folder content of another location.

I'd like to do the same things in firebase's Realtime Database. I'd like to take `viewerPath` and let it "see" the data that exists at `ownerPath`. I could copy the data over, but I'd need to keep doing it every time `ownerPath` is updated. If I could add something like a symbolic link instead this would be a more elegant and clean solution.

Is this possible in firebase? Have not managed to find a definite answer.

Comment: Firebase consists of 18 or so products. Which specific one are you asking about? Note: I expect the answer to be "no" for all of them, but there might be different workarounds for different products.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Realtime Database. Also updating the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases what you're describing would be a managed foreign key. Nothing similar exists in Realtime Database however. While you can (and often will) store the key of one node as the value somewhere else, Firebase won't know anything about the meaning of such values - and not do anything with them.

Duplicating data is extremely common in NoSQL databases, so I highly recommend embracing it. Once you do, you can start looking at how to then manage the duplicated data, for example by letting Cloud Functions take care of updating the duplicates.

Also see:

- my answer here: [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)
- this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- the video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping to use this in conjunction with the Realtime Database rules, but I'll just go the route of handling data duplication when necessary.