# Best Practice to keep user data in firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firebase as a backend for my Android App. And this app is a social media app where users can post, comment & like. so I am storing user data in `user_collection` and this collection is secured by security rules where if `uid == auth.uid` (any user can only access data of himself).

Now in this app when a user post something every user can see this post. And in post_collection I am saving userId in post_doc.

So the problem is I need to show name of user to other users and I have only userId but the problem is a user can't get name of other user by uid beacuse of security rules. now I have to solutions for this **please tell me which one is better or you can also suggest any other solutions also?**

1. I can use cloud functions `getUserNameById()` (Problem : I need to call this function very frequently in feed when user scroll)
2. I can store name also in `post_doc` (problem : when user changes his name then It will show old name in old post)

Thanks for you kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a scenario like the one you describe, I would typically store the user name in each post doc. I would also ignore updates to the name, as I think of the user name in the post doc as a historical value: this is the name the user had when they posted this. Now you may want different behavior of course, in which case I recommend reading: [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase)

---

Your approach with Cloud Functions is fine too, and quite common in some situations. But I tend to only use Cloud Functions for reading data, it the read operation itself is particularly complex, which isn't the case here. In a case like this, I'd recommend coming up with a data model that allows the use-case and security you want.

For example: if you create a collection `usernames` where each document has the UID as its document ID, and then contains a single field with the username for that UID, you could implement the lookup of the user name through Firestore.

So you could have:

1. Store the full user profile in `/users/$uid`.
2. Store the user name in `/usernames/$uid`.
3. Have a Cloud Function that triggers when `/users/$uid` is written and that updates `/usernames/$uid`.
4. The client then has read access to each `/usernames/$uid` document, or even to the entire `/usernames` collection in one go if needed.

This way the names can be cached on the client, and continue to work when the app is offline, unlike in your approach with a Cloud Function that looks up the user name.

Comment: Thank You So Much, I have accepted your answer. the link of another question is very helpful & I am going with *Not Caring*  approach .lol .....

Answer (score 1):

Consider the solution: whatever public data you need (author name, author userpic link etc) just save it with the post at the time it had created.
So your Message Pojo will looks like:

- id
- authorName
- text

etc..

and just display this name (authorName).
It will be the bad way to go any time to User_collection folder to take the name even if there are would be not strict security (becouse it takes time and document reads)