# How to query normalized firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Database that looks like this:

```
Root
    Accounts
            username: UID1
    Friends
            id: SOME_ID
            members: {UID1, UID2}
```

I display all the friends in a `RecyclerView`. But how can I use the `username` field in the `Accounts` collection to query the `Friends` List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current data model you'll have to load each friend's user profile separately based on their UID to get their username.

Alternatively you can change your data model to also include the user name for each member in the `Friends` document already. While this data duplication may seem unnatural if you come from a background in relational databases, it is really common in NoSQL databases - and one of the reasons they scale so well when reading data.

To learn more about this, also check out:

- This article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- Todd's excellent video series: [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)
- My answer on [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase). While written for Realtime Database, it applies equally to Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/player/:id", async (req, res) => {
  
  let { id: playerId } = req.params;
  if (!playerId) {
    res.status(400).send({
      success: false,
      message: "Kindly provide player ID",
    });
    return 0;
  }
  try {
    const snapshot = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("players")// players root user
      .doc(playerId)  //  sub folder   
      .get();
    let userData = snapshot.data();
    if (userData) {
      res.status(200).send({ ...userData });
      return 0;
    } else {
      res.status(400).send({
        success: false,
        message: "player does not exists in database",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: err.message });
  }
});
```