# In Firestore, is updating data across multiple collections and subcollections the correct approach?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Say that I have a collection of POSTS with information like `uid`, `title`, `username`, `profileImage` etc. I have thousands of posts.

Now my user updates their `username` or `profileImage` then I thinking of having a listener on cloud function that update all collections and subcollections that reference that user `uid` to update either the `username` or the `profileImage` so all collections and subcollections are update with the latest user information.

I know the above approach works but is this really the way to do it in firestore considering cost and efficiency.

Comment: There is not really one "the way" to do this; it all depend on your use-cases, tolerance/need for to show historical values, and much more. I outlined the 3 most common approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277#30699277

Answer (score 0):

you really don't need username and profile in your post collection, you have this in your usermodel. you only need uid  and reference in it. The proper way to update a document is by using reference.

Comment: In NoSQL databases it is *very* common to duplicate data at write time, to avoid having to look it up at read time. There is no "proper way" here like you often see for relational databases. In NoSQL it all depends on the use-cases of the app and the data involved in those.

Comment: If you're new to NoSQL, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Denormalizing your data is normal](https://firebase.blog/posts/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal/) and watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much for this ! Yes! I'm new to noSQL data modeling. Denormalization is the word I was missing in my vocabulary. looks like duplication of data is not a problem and modeling my data after the views of my app is the way to go from what I gathered from the "Denormalization video".  I will keep educating myself on this. thank you