# SQL, select from one table, change a field, update that field in second table

Tags: sql

I've never asked a question here before, and I'm not very advanced with sql whatsoever beyond simple queries so I apologize if I sound inept, very different from the programming I am used to. But today I am stuck in a unique position trying to solve a problem with no assistance, so I am hoping to get some ideas on here or knowledge.

I have Table A and Table B. They have various different columns except for the two they have in common, ID and phone number. Sometimes, a few rows in Table B will have NULL in the phone number. I need to write something that will select all records from Table A by ID and phone number, look up the same IDs in Table B, and if B's phone number field is NULL it will update it with the phone number from A.

I really hope this makes sense. I had begun writing a loop to try to accomplish this by iteration as I might with my other programming but everywhere I read said SQL was not made to do loops so stay away. I appreciate any input.

Taylor

Comment: Welcome! What RDBMS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i believe you are looking for an answer like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/6242681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the results you want by creating a `Select` statement.

```
Select A.ID as AID, B.ID as BID, A.Phone as APhone, B.Phone as BPhone
From TableA A
JOIN TableB B on A.ID = B.ID
Where B.Phone is Null
```

Then you can form this into your `Update` statement very easily.

```
Update B
Set Phone = A.Phone
From TableA A
    JOIN TableB B on A.ID = B.ID
    Where B.Phone is Null
```

Comment: this should  work for you @TaylorMeow, in addition you can add isnull function if B.Phone is sometimes empty, other time NULL. where isnull(B.Phone, '') = ''

Comment: OMG! That works! I'm still forming the update part but my results were exactly the records I needed with the right fields! Ah I'm so relieved my day might not be so bad afterall. I cannot thank you all enough for the help. I think this where I make my comment there were a lot of places to add one... But yes this is resolved I'm happy as a clam.

Comment: Glad this worked for you @TaylorMeow. Please accept this as your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would check this out: [Updating denormalized database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517609/updating-denormalized-database-tables)

You could eliminate this problem by "normalizing" the tables and getting rid of redundant sets of data. However, denormalized data can be more efficient than normalized data in certain situations.